# Is it possible fetch details of installed apps on another iphone from my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently doing an app which requires the details of installed apps on another iPhone from my iPhone (or any other iDevices).

My requirement is :

1. My app will push the data, if my app is installed on both device
2. Otherwise it'll have to send a link to download that app.

Is it possible?

I want to detect if app is instlled on another phone or not.

Is there any API bundle available? I am making it in Xcode.

Comment: How are you establishing communication with the other device?

Comment: Lefteris the devices will have to communicate through Bump API- anyway dude?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. As Apple will not allow you to fetch the information of user's personal device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
You can't even know the apps installed on your own iDevice

Comment: can't think of alternatives. tHANK YOU @jcesar